# Adding raster data to Table of Contents using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, layers

I can easily add shapefiles to the Table of Contents in ArcMap using the following code:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current") 
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
path = os.path.abspath("shapefile_path")
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd, addLayer
```

but I am confused how to add raster data (which usually consists of several files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by a very similar means.

1. Use ArcMap to add your raster dataset to a map as a layer
2. Set whatever Layer Properties you want
3. Save the layer just authored as a layer file (*.lyr)
4. Use [arcpy.mapping.AddLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000008000000) to reference such "layers in a layer (.lyr) file".

If you want to automate the layer authoring process (steps 1-3) then try [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006t000000) followed by [Save To Layer File](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Save_To_Layer_File/001700000070000000/).